# Regex Value for Java Case Insensitive

Tags: java, regex

I wrote one regular expression for catching any special characters in the text.

```
regular expression: (?i)[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.-^*()%!]
```

I am passing a text "Testing" but getting output that the text contains special characters. But as soon as i pass, "testing" with small "t", i am getting no error.. Can you please help ?

code:

```
String REGEX = "(?i)[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.-^*()%!]";
String fieldValue="Testing";
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(REGEX);
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fieldValue);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String strWarningMessage = "Field value cannot contain Special Characters";
    System.out.println(strWarningMessage);
}
else
    System.out.println("OK");
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I've edited the parenthesis in your `if`, I hope it was a typo only when you posted the question. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't think you should be getting an error. What's the message?

Comment: It's not an error message, it prints my warning message only: Field value cannot contain Special Characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `-` to the end of the character class or escape it:

```
"[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]"
```

And the `(?i)` can be dropped, since your pattern doesn't specify any character which has different cases.

In your original regex, `.-^` is specifying a range of character from `.` (U+002E) to `^` (U+005E), which contains uppercase `A-Z` and digits `0-9`.

Comment: Shouldn't have `^`? OP doesn't want to match any special character.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Don't know. There are numerous other "special character" in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is character `-`. 
When symbol group `[...]` contains this character, there are two possible interpretation:

- symbol `-` (when it placed in first position after `[`)
- symbol range (when it placed in any position after `[` except first)

So you need move `-` to start of symbol group.